# Update openssl version in the guardianproject/openssl-android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, openssl

I downloaded the openssl-android folder from the [guardianproject page](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android)  and followed the steps in the README.android file but I'm blocked at the third step when I import the new openssl tar, as it is written in step 2 I changed the openssl.version file and the openssl.config file with the correct variables.
When running the import_openssl.sh script, there were some errors coming from an incorrect path in the .patch files which I updated but one problem persists with the handshake_cutthrough.patch file, I first updated the paths in there, regenerated the patch file and restarted the script with the same error but with a new message:
Here's the trace:

```
./import_openssl.sh import ../openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
Applying patch progs.patch
patching file apps/openssl.c 
Applying patch small_records.patch
patching file ssl/d1_pkt.c
patching file ssl/s23_srvr.c
patching file ssl/s3_both.c
patching file ssl/s3_pkt.c
patching file ssl/ssl.h
patching file ssl/ssl3.h
patching file ssl/ssltest.c
patching file test/testssl
Applying patch handshake_cutthrough.patch
patching file apps/s_client.c
patching file ssl/s3_clnt.c
patching file ssl/s3_lib.c
patching file ssl/ssl.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #2 FAILED at 1411.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file ssl/ssl.h.rej
Could not apply patches/handshake_cutthrough.patch. Fix source and run: /import_openssl.sh regenerate patches/handshake_cutthrough.patch
```

First I don't have any idea of the meaning of the message Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? and what to answer except y or n.
Secondly I almost think about forgetting the idea of importing the new openssl version (1.0.1e) and work with the one included in the package which is the 1.0.0. From there I'll ask two questions:
1) Did somebody encounter these problems?
2) Is there an important security difference between openssl1.0.0 and openssl1.0.1e?

Many thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First I don't have any idea of the meaning of the message
>   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R?
>   and what to answer except y or n.

Yeah, that's one of those patch-isms that rates high on the usability scale. When its asking you if you want to reverse it, its asking if you want to remove a previously applied patch from a source file. In my opinion, it should (1) add it if not present, or (2) move on if present. There is no (3) torture the user. If I supply a switch (perhaps `-prompt`) or run `unpatch`, then I should be asked 20 questions. Otherwise, just apply the damn patch.

> Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y

I believe you should have answered NO here by typing `n`. It was asking you to remove a previously applied patch.